# How to fill down empty cells in a CSV in AWK?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV file like this, with `@` as the delimiter:

```
Chapter 1@This is some text.
        @This is some more text.
        @This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
        @This is some more text.
        @This is yet some more text.
```

The first column contains the chapter number. The second column contains the text of the chapter.

I need to fill down all of the chapter number in column A, such that any empty cells below are filled with the chapter number. E.g., the output would be this:

```
Chapter 1@This is some text.
Chapter 1@This is some more text.
Chapter 1@This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
Chapter 2@This is some more text.
Chapter 2@This is yet some more text.
```

How can I fill down all of the empty cells in column A of the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"} {if ($1 ~ /^[ \t]*$/) $1=ch; else ch=$1} 1' file

Chapter 1@This is some text.
Chapter 1@This is some more text.
Chapter 1@This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
Chapter 2@This is some more text.
Chapter 2@This is yet some more text.
```

Using a simple regex check we verify if `$1` is not-empty then we set variable ch`as name of the first chapter. Then in next subsequent lines we set chapter name to the value we've stored in variable`ch`.

Answer (score 2):

Other way using `awk`

**Input**

```
$ cat file
Chapter 1@This is some text.
        @This is some more text.
        @This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
        @This is some more text.
        @This is yet some more text.
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"}/^[ \t]+/{$1=c}{c=$1}1' file
Chapter 1@This is some text.
Chapter 1@This is some more text.
Chapter 1@This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
Chapter 2@This is some more text.
Chapter 2@This is yet some more text.

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"}/^[^\t ]+/{c=$1}{$1=c}1' file
Chapter 1@This is some text.
Chapter 1@This is some more text.
Chapter 1@This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
Chapter 2@This is some more text.
Chapter 2@This is yet some more text.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution -

```
awk -F@  '$1!~/^[[:space:]]+/ {h=$1FS} {print ($1!~/^[[:space:]]+/? $0 : h$2)}' f
Chapter 1@This is some text.
Chapter 1@This is some more text.
Chapter 1@This is yet some more text.
Chapter 2@This is some text.
Chapter 2@This is some more text.
Chapter 2@This is yet some more text.
```